# How to create a carousel type banner with rotating images on Broadleaf-Ecommerce.

Tags: html, thymeleaf, broadleaf-commerce

I want to make carousel type banner with rotating imageson home page of Broadleaf E-commerce template. I am not able to figure out how to achieve this. Please guide me on this.

I tried with following code in home.html but nothing getting displayed.

```
<blc:content contentType="Homepage Banner Ad" />       
        <div id="banners" th:if="${contentItem !=null and contentItem['targetUrl'] != null and contentItem['imageUrl'] != null}">
           <ul>
             <li th:each="contentItem : ${contentItems}">
                <a th:href="@{${contentItem['targetUrl']}}"><img th:src="@{${contentItem['imageUrl']}}" style="width:100%;"/></a> 
            </li>

           </ul> 
        </div>
```

I have added 3 banner images through admin pannel with priority 1,2 and 3

Answer (score 0):

For carousel you will need to use javascript or any other equivalent client side scripting. I prefer [jCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/) and [Jssor Slider](http://www.jssor.com/index.html).

Comment: im Using Boradleaf template and i want to try somthing within itself.ie we add images through admin pannel into data base and i want to show all the images from database to be displayed as banner.Now im only able to fetch a single image from db.

Comment: As per the code you have mentioned I feel that blc:content return only single image. See https://github.com/BroadleafCommerce/BroadleafCommerce/blob/334289cfd658b6563a952f39b18e52c09caf0574/admin/broadleaf-contentmanagement-module/src/main/java/org/broadleafcommerce/cms/web/processor/ContentProcessor.java

Comment: Can you explain more or suggest how to achieve this

Comment: In <blc:content contentType="Homepage Banner Ad" /> "content" is thymeleaf processro and content type identifies what type of image needs to be added in the Model object. Here bolc:content returns only one image that you see in demo aplication. Now you can override this processor or create your own which fetches the images  from DB and brings it to the view page. Then on view page you can use javascript library to show carousel.

To get more knowledge on thymeleaf processor refer http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/extendingthymeleaf.html